# Osmdroid - change local map folder

Tags: android, zip, osmdroid

I am using offline version of osmdroid, maps are placed in sdcard/osmdroid. Do you know, how to change the file path?  I have been searching through their code for handling ZIP files but I haven't found any solution. Anyone faced this issue before?

Thx

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/constants/OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.java

Comment: @blackbelt - that looks spot on. static and final in an interface, so unless you build your own version from source, you're stuck with what's there.

Comment: thanks, now I will need to change it. And do you know blackbelt, where in osmdroid are handling unzipping ZIP files? Make it a reply then, I will give you a reputation points. Thx

Comment: NickT - oh, thats bad... I don't think it is available for download as a cource to build on your own...

Comment: @Waypoint - Yes, you can get a copy of the source, I've not done it myself, but if you use subversion it's available at http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/checkout

Comment: svn checkout http://osmdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ osmdroid-read-only . use svn to checkout the osmdroid source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/checkout) you can check out the code to build your own version of OSMdroid. Changing ZIP and local folder is totally possbile, had to do it myself a few months ago.

Responsible for the Zips are this classes:

```
org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/ZipFileArchive.java
org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/MapTileFileArchiveProvider.java
```

Comment: thanks Thommy, I am using eclipse and I don't see here any svn bridge solution? Do I need to install some plugin to be able to check out OSMdroid source code?

Comment: You can do the checkout with you preferred svn tool. Eclipse plugin or standalone tool - that doesn't matter. You just need to delete all .svn Folders in the project after checkout.

Answer (score 4):

If you download the package of code about osmdroid: `osmdroid-android-3.0.8-sources`, you can open the class `OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.java` and modify the variable in this way:

**modify**

`public static final File OSMDROID_PATH = new File("/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid");`

`to*`

`public static final File OSMDROID_PATH = new File("/mnt/ext_sdcard/yourfile");`

Then put your map tiles into `yourfile`.

Comment: This looks like it will work, but I don't want to fork and compile my own library. I'll just stick to sdcard. Why did they put final on it?

Comment: i think because they want to make it unchanged. @TomKincaid :D