# Change OSMDroid tiles path

Tags: android, osmdroid

I searched stackoverflow for this, I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568079/osmdroid-change-local-map-folder) with the correct answer, but I need help on making it right.

What I'm asking here is how can I use the jar file (instead of osmdroid source) and be able to change this constant to some other folder in my sdcard?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: If that's not possible, how can I use the source on my project? Thanks.

Comment: checkout the source code and follow this guide: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToEclipse

Comment: @blackbelt I followed that guide and now what do I need to do to use it on my project? Thanks!

Comment: in the source code you checked out there is an example. Follow it

Comment: I exported that project as an java .jar and imported to my project and it worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blackbelt suggestion:

- checkout the source code and follow this guide: code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToEclipse
- export that project as an java .jar and import it to your project!